# Cannot send input after starting communication

Tags: java, python

I am working on a project that compiles and runs a Java program through Python. I want Python to be able to send inputs to the Java program if requested.

Currently, I have a list of expected commands that should be sent through the shell when the java program requests it. My current thoughts include:

```
commands = [5]
proc = subprocess.Popen('./java test', shell=True, universal_newlines=True, stdout=subprocess.PIPE, stderr=subprocess.PIPE, stdin=subprocess.PIPE)
if(len(commands) > 0):
   for x in commands:
       proc.communicate(x)
```

For a very basic java program:

```
import System;

public class A {
    public static void main() {
       int x = 0;
       System.out.print("Input value for x: ");
       x = System.out.readInt();
    }

}
```

I am getting the error: Cannot send input after starting communication

Any recommendations/is this possible?

Comment: What's going wrong? Any errors?

Comment: `java.lang.System` is part of `java.lang` and imported by default. Controlling a Java process from a Python process is not my idea of good design. Write the code in a single Java process or a single Python process. Don't try and mix and match without a very good reason. Your trivial examples here are not good reasons. `x = System.out.readInt();` is not even close to legal Java code. This entire exercise feels wrong.

Comment: Yes, the error is:Cannot send input after starting communication

Comment: @ElliottFrisch the purpose is not good design, rather testing possibilities.

Comment: Do you really have `System.out.readInt();` or is it really `System.in.readInt();`?

Comment: @Tim I suspect it doesn't compile because of `import System;`

Comment: @ElliottFrisch Compilation is not the problem. Maybe I over simplified the java program. The important part of the question stems from being able to send commands when Java requests it.

Comment: What you're doing is a perfectly ordinary pipeline.  You do need to send something from Python for the Java code to read, and I don't see that here.

Comment: @TimRoberts even with System.in.readInt() there is the error of "...Cannot send input after starting communication" from Python

Comment: `proc.stdin.write( "37\n" );`

Comment: Can you post the full error? (preferably in your question so that it's easier to read)

Comment: For best results, you should not have the Java app print a prompt.  That will all back up in the pipe buffers, which are not infinitely large. The alternative is to have the Python code read that data occasionally.

Comment: @TimRoberts I think I am asking this poorly. I want multiple commands to be communicated (not shown in question). i.e ```commands = ['5', '5']``` however, after one communication is opened - the error occurs. Is there a way to pass a command everytime reading occurs?

Comment: Right, I know that.  Don't have the Java do a prompt.  You just keep doing `proc.stdin.write( "5\n" )` for as many commands as you have.  They'll all back up until the Java reads them.  Then, you'll need to have a way to terminate the app.

Comment: Ohhhh, I see. I understand better now. Thank you @TimRoberts